Issue with Yup Validation Not Displaying Errors in React Native
I'm working on a login screen in a React Native application using react-hook-form and yupfor form validation. I've implemented a feature that allows users to choose the sign-up method either by email or phone number.
The problem I'm encountering is that validation error messages for the email or phone number fields are not displayed when the form is submitted empty or when the input does not meet the validation rules. Only the password field's error message is shown.
the error message don't show with the email
the error message don't show with the phone number
PS: the logIn function works fine with both email and phone number
....... 
 const [signUpMethod, setSignUpMethod] = useState("phoneNumber");
 const schema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string().when("signUpMethod", {
      is: "email",
      then: yup
        .string()
        .required("You should enter an email")
        .email("Invalid email"),
    }),
    phoneNumber: yup.string().when("signUpMethod", {
      is: "phoneNumber",
      then: yup
        .string()
        .required("You should enter a phone number")
        .matches(
          /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/,
          "Phone number is not valid"
        ),
    }),
    password: yup.string().required("You should enter a password"),
  });

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
    },
  });

  const onPressSend = async (formData) => {
    console.log(" ~ onPressSend ~ formData:", formData);
    const { email, phoneNumber, password } = formData;
    const number = "+" + countryCode + phoneNumber;
    const loginData =
      signUpMethod === "email"
        ? { username: email, password }
        : { username: number, password };
    console.log(" ~ onPressSend ~ loginData:", loginData);
    try {
      dispatch(loginRequest());
      login({ variables: loginData }).then((res) => {
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data.login));
        console.log(" ~ login ~ res:", res);
      });
      console.log(" ~ login ~ res.data.login:", res.data.login);
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(loginFailure(error.message));
      setErrorMessage(error.message);
      console.log("====>", error);
    }
  };
...
  return (
...
   <View style={styles.singUpMethod}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={
                signUpMethod === "email"
                  ? styles.selectedMethod
                  : styles.notSelectedMethod
              }
              onPress={() => {
                setSignUpMethod("email");
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={
                  signUpMethod === "email"
                    ? styles.selectedMethodText
                    : styles.notSelectedMethodText
                }
              >
                Email
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={
                signUpMethod === "phoneNumber"
                  ? styles.selectedMethod
                  : styles.notSelectedMethod
              }
              onPress={() => {
                setSignUpMethod("phoneNumber");
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={
                  signUpMethod === "phoneNumber"
                    ? styles.selectedMethodText
                    : styles.notSelectedMethodText
                }
              >
                Phone
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          {signUpMethod === "email" && (
            <Controller
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: true }}
              render={({ field: { onChange, value, onBlur } }) => (
                <>
                  <TextInput
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    value={value}
                    onChangeText={onChange}
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor={Colors.SmokeBlue}
                    placeholder="Enter your Email"
                  />
                  {errors.email && (
                    <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>
                      {errors.email.message}
                    </Text>
                  )}
                </>
              )}
              name="email"
            />
          )}
          {signUpMethod === "phoneNumber" && (
            <View>
              <View style={styles.inline}>
                <CountryPicker
                  disable={false}
                  animationType={"slide"}
                  language="en"
                  containerStyle={styles.pickerStyle}
                  pickerTitleStyle={styles.pickerTitleStyle}
                  selectedCountryTextStyle={styles.selectedCountryTextStyle}
                  countryNameTextStyle={styles.countryNameTextStyle}
                  pickerTitle={"Country Picker"}
                  searchBarPlaceHolder={"Search......"}
                  hideCountryFlag={false}
                  hideCountryCode={false}
                  searchBarStyle={styles.searchBarStyle}
                  countryCode={countryCode}
                  selectedValue={(text) => {
                    setCountryCode(text);
                  }}
                />
                <Controller
                  control={control}
                  rules={{
                    required: true,
                  }}
                  render={({ field: { onChange, value, onBlur } }) => (
                    <TextInput
                      onBlur={onBlur}
                      value={value}
                      onChangeText={onChange}
                      style={styles.phoneInput}
                      placeholderTextColor={Colors.SmokeBlue}
                      placeholder="Phone number"
                    />
                  )}
                  name="phoneNumber"
                />
              </View>
              {errors.phoneNumber && (
                <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>
                  {errors.phoneNumber.message}
                </Text>
              )}
            </View>
          )}

          <Controller
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value, onBlur } }) => (
              <TextInput
                onBlur={onBlur}
                value={value}
                onChangeText={onChange}
                style={styles.input}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                placeholderTextColor={Colors.SmokeBlue}
                placeholder="Enter your password"
              />
            )}
            name="password"
          />
          {errors.password && (
            <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{errors.password.message}</Text>
          )}
 <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={handleSubmit(onPressSend)}
            style={styles.button}
          >
     
              <Text style={styles.login}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
.....
  );
}





i'm no yup expert, but at first glance at the docs (and similar SO questions), it looks like you may need to adjust your "then" properties to use lambdas that use the schema itself.  ie: yup.object({ email: yup.string().when('signUpMethod', { is: 'phoneNumber', then: (schema) => { schema.required().email('invalid email') } }) })
looked at docs:
link
could be wrong, but easy to try.
